# 429 Error in authorization with Instagram on first login

Tags: api, facebook, authorization, instagram-api

We have an issue with Instagram.

My team is currently facing an issue with Instagram authorization, when we try to login first it shows a Facebook login page where we insert username and password. Then it redirect us to Instagram login page with URL( [https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&scope=user_profile,user_media](https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=%7Bclient_id%7D&redirect_uri=%7Bredirect_uri%7D&scope=user_profile,user_media) ). It throws a 429 error but if we refresh the page and try to login again where we do same process but this time we only enter password it works fine. We can't figure out or find what the issue is. Is it from our side? is it from Instagram (Meta) side? what can we do to solve this?

we checked our dashboard and it's not even near the rate limit.

I found a [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/533100984908054/?join_id=f18b7acf7eb02d8)  report on Facebook bugs but it's not quite helpful.